# My function does not plot the proper range

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I am trying to plot a simple function: `y = sqrt(x+4)-2`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[ 
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel={$y$},
        axis x line=center, axis y line=center
        ] 
        \addplot[domain=-5:5,
        color=red] {sqrt(x+4)-2}; 
    \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

I get:

[image]

The min y value should be -2 at x = -4, but I get -1.5. How is that? Thank you!

Comment: Well, you ask pgfplots to plot this all the way down to -5 by saying `domain=-5:5`. What should it plot below `x=-4`?

Comment: @marmot I don't understand because -5 < -4, no? It shouldn't plot anything below -4 because the function would not be defined.

Comment: restrict your domain to `-4:4`. now the function is drawn to about `x=-3.5` because your number of samples is to small than can follows slope of function. or define `samples=500` for example.

Comment: @Zarko Thank you very much, it worked! I thought that it would plot like a graphic calculator (or perhaps the calculator uses the same strategy).

Comment: @Johnathan, you actually have math problem: how to draw complex function on real plane :-). see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- defining `domain=-5:5` require, that `pgfplots` below `-4` draw complex function, what is not possible. so sensible is, that the lower domain limit is `-4`.
- tangent to function at `x=-4` is orthogonal, so the default number of samples is to small that can follows to function change

the simplest solution is

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel={$y$},
        axis lines=center,
       %samples=400% for more smuth curve
            ]
   \addplot[domain=-4:5, color=red] {sqrt(x+4)-2};
   \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Ok, so because we approach a limit (x = -4), we need more points  for latex to estimats how the curve behaves at that point, right?

Comment: @Johnathan, yes. you can help `pgfplots` with splitting plots on two parts: `\adplot[domain:-4:-3,5, samples=70,red] {sqrt(x+4)-2};\adplot[domain:-3.5:5, samples=70,red] {sqrt(x+4)-2};`

Answer (score 2):

You do not need any large number of samples if you just realize that what you are drawing is a flipped parabola.

```
\documentclass[margin=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel={$y$},
        axis lines=center]
   \addplot[domain=-2:1.5, color=red] ({(x+2)^2-4},{x});
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]